# How can I hide/show a bootstrap navbar in Meteor on scroll?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I want to hide the bootstrap navbar when I scroll down but show the bootstrap navbar when I scroll upwards.

This is a common Navbar reaction on most mobile phone apps, for instance on Whatsapp.

I successfully coded the desirable effect in an HTML page which you'll find attached. I can't get it to work in my meteor App, or don't know how to get it to work on my meteor App, hence me looking for a meteor package.

Does anyone know how I can get the code below to work in a meteor environment?

html:

```
<header class="navbar-default">
This is your menu.
<script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javaScript.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</header>

<main>
   This is your body.
</main>

<footer>
   This is your footer.
</footer>
```

And below the CSS file:

```
body {
padding-top: 40px;
}

/*
header {
background: #f5b335;
height: 40px;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
width: 100%;
}
*/

.navbar-default{
background-color: #ea5b31;
border-color: #ea5b31;
margin-bottom: 0px;
height: 50px;
position: fixed;
top: -1px;
width: 100%;
transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.nav-up {
top: -40px;
}

main {
background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAPklEQVQYV2O8dOnSfwYg0NPTYwTRuAAj0QqxmYBNM1briFaIzRbi3UiRZ75uNgUHGbfvabgfsHqGaIXYPAMAD8wgC/DOrZ4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=
) repeat;
height: 2000px;
}

footer { background: #ddd;}
* { color: transparent}
```

And a version of my JavaScript file:

```
// Hide Header on on scroll down
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
if (didScroll) {
    hasScrolled();
    didScroll = false;
}
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
var st = $(this).scrollTop();

// alert("st VALUE is: " +st);

// Make sure they scroll more than delta
if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
    return;

// If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
// This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
    // Scroll Down
    $('header').removeClass('navbar-default').addClass('nav-up');
//       alert("You are scrolling down!");
//       alert(+st+ " > " +lastScrollTop+ " && " +st+ " > " +navbarHeight);
} else {
    // Scroll Up
    if(st + $(window).height() > $(document).height()) {
//          alert(+st+ " + " +$(window).height()+ " < "     +$(document).height() )
        $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('navbar-default');
    }
}

lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

Comment: @Santi his question is a valid question - he asked how to achieve a specific result and provided his attempt so far. The fact that he asked for a recommendation of a package is irrelevant because he doesn't need a package to achieve this

Comment: @Sean - You are correct, I hadn't noticed he also mentions: *"or perhaps how I can get the code below to work in a meteor environment?"*. That being said, the focus of the post should be changed to reflect that; both the title and opening sentence of the post explicitly request an off-site resource.

Comment: @Sean The desired/primary solution is for a meteor Package, hence the tile. The "perhaps how I can get the code below to work in a meteor environment?" indicates a secondary solution...

Comment: @SirBT There isn't a package to add an effect to your application's navbar. That's like me asking for a package that will make my application's navbar flash red and black every two seconds.  I was defending your question as a valid question even though your 'desired solution' is nonsense so I'm not sure why you are acting like I didn't understand it

Comment: @Sean My apologies! The post was intended for Santi

Comment: @Santi The desired/primary solution is for a meteor Package, hence the tile. The "perhaps how I can get the code below to work in a meteor environment?" indicates a secondary solution...

Comment: @SirBT *"The desired/primary solution is for a meteor Package"* - Then your question should be closed. Questions that seek off-site resources are considered off-topic on this website, which is why I said you should modify your "desired/primary solution". Per [What topics can I ask about?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow..."*